# Prove via induction this recursively defined sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

Let $P(n) = 2P(n-1) + n, P(1) = 3.$ Use induction to show that $$P(n) = 3(2^n) - n - 2$$

Highly verbose solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where  are you stuck?

Comment: Usually, my professor solves these by doing something along these lines: take the non recursive portion, suppose it is true for p(n-1), then plug that into the recursive portion to replace n-1, and then simplify. How this works, as an inductive argument is beyond me. Perhaps a little clarification for this method, and if you're familiar with it, a solution with explanation of thought process? Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Actually, I solved it, but I do not have sufficient reputation to post my answer yet. You'll hear back from me in a few hours...

Comment: If you want a proof by induction, I am not sure where you are having trouble.  The inductive step is simply:
$$P(n+1) = 2P(n)+(n+1) = 2\left(3(2^n)-n-2\right) + (n+1) = 3(2^{n+1})-n-3$$

Comment: Yes this is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found after consulting some other people with this issue, and some additional study materials:

Let $p(n) = 3(2^n)-n-2$ for $n>=1$, then $p(1) = 3$, so $p(1)$ is true.

Suppose $k>1$ is an integer and $p(k-1)$ is true. So $p(k-1) = 3(2^{k-1})-(k-1)-2$

By the given relation:

$p(k) = 2(3(2^{k-1})-(k-1)-2)+k$

Simplify:

$p(k) = 3(2^k)-k-2$

So it is true that $p(n) = 3(2^n)-n-2$ for $n>=1$

Answer (score 0):

The formation of the question suggests that a general solution is of the type: $$P(n) = k\cdot2^n + an + b$$ with integers $a, b , k$. So $P(1) = 3 \implies 3 = 2k + a + b$ (1). Let $n = 2$ in the equation, $P(2) = 2\cdot3 + 2 = 8 = 4k + 2a + b$ (2), and let $n = 3$ gives: $P(3) = 2\cdot8 + 3 = 19 = 8k + 3a + b$ (3).

Solving the system (1), (2), and (3) gives: $b = -2, a = -1, k = 3$. So $P(n) = 3\cdot2^n - n - 2$.

Comment: Any methods that avoid using systems of equations?

Comment: You can use generating function.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @jvb93: ok. let a(0) = 1, and a(n) = 3*a(n-1) + 1. Find a formula for a(n). You let A(x) = a(0) + a(1)x + a(2)x^2 +...+ a(n)x^n +....then you plug 3*a(n-1) + 1 in place of a(n), and split it in two sums and in term of A(x). Solve A(x) and expand A(x) as a power series, then the n-th term of the power series is the n-th term of your sequence. Try it.

Comment: This is pretty cool, though isn't exactly what my professor is looking for, unfortunately. I do appreciate your response.